# How do I copy one mesh's properties and apply it to another mesh in blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, properties

In Blender v2.70, I've created a mesh from scratch to serve as a custom head in The Sims 4.  However, when I try to use Sims4Studio to import it, it doesn't work because I have to apparently alter one of the pre-existing heads.  Therein lies my problem: I have a mesh that I want to use, but can't, so I need to copy it's vertices locations, sculpt data, etc., and paste that info onto the head mesh the Sims4Studio provides me with.

How do I do that?

Comment: You could probably assign the mesh of your head to the preexisting object, replacing its mesh. If vertices count is the same, it could just work, but I can't try, I have not Sims4studio.

Comment: Actually I think you will need to use the original mesh, uv's and vertex order... I would try shrinkwrapping the original mesh to your new head model. The [snapping tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) can be used to align the old head onto the surface of the new one. A tutorial on retopology can explain it.